# PayPal REST API Billing Plan State Active

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I am Created in New Plan ID for ID State is Created After doing Subscription for Agreement but before Plan ID state are Change In Active this Such as coding but its getting on error .

curl -v -k -X PATCH 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
    -d '[
        {
            "path": "/",
            "value": {
                "state": "ACTIVE"
            },
            "op": "replace"
        }
    ]'

Response error.

{"name":"BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"validation_error","issue":"Plan already in same state."}],"message":"Validation Error.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"f03711ef797b8"}

Comment: I am checked sandbox

Comment: looks like your Plan is already active.

Comment: Checked with retrieve the Plan state is Created ..